# Логика для Windows Form

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, login

Изучаю Windows Form на С++. Пытаюсь построить форму входа в приложение или что то вроде того. Для тренировки/изучения. Хотел для тренировки использовать банальные переменные а не базу или файлы.

Подскажите пожалуйста как а главное куда внести код типа:

```
string user = "Asd";
string password = "qwerty";
if (form.user==user && form.password==password){
   std::cout << "You can join\n";
} else {
     std::cout << "Name or password illigal\n";
```

}

Comment: @こきん - пожалуйста, не удаляйте слишком рьяно метки C++ у всех вопросов с упоминанием WinForms. В данном вопросе пока ничего не относится к C++/CLI, а приведённый пример кода написан как раз на C++.

Comment: Если вы изучаете именно C++, то забудьте про WinForms, потому что это это GUI-фреймворк для платформы .NET. И писать вам придётся на C++/CLI - а это совершенно другой язык.

Comment: А если вы изучаете WinForms, то забудьте про C++, возьмите язык C#.